# What is adb error on Android?

Tags: adb, side-loading

I want to send a file from my PC in Android recovery mode, but I can not get an error. The error is as follows:

- adb push file.zip

> *daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> could not read ok from ADB server
>
> *faild to start daemon
>
> adb.: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon
>
> And if you use Advacnced> ADB Sideload> Swip from an Android device from https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/sideload-flashable-zips-android-with-twrp-0176529/ an error was displayed . How do I solve it?

- Data successfully decrypted , new block device: '/dev /block/dm- 0'
- Updating partition details . . . . . .
- done
- Unable to mount storage
- Successfully decrypted with default password.
- Updating partition details . . .
- .. .done
- Unable to mount storage
- Failed to mount '/data ' (Invalid argument )
- Full SELinux support is present.
- Unable to mount /data/media /TWRP/ . twrps
- MTP. Enabled
- Starting ADB sideload feature...